# Adding the Group Name in URL and Accessing that URL without index Page

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The users can create their own group in my site.

They can create with their desired group name.

That is, "**http://mysite.com/groups/" *_*__*_*__*_***

--**Ex:** `http://mysite.com/groups/test_group`

('http://mysite.com/groups/' is default then the users can add the their desired name and i have maintained with unique name).

I have one index.php in 'groups' directory.

I **dont want** to access with "`http://mysite.com/groups/index.php?name=test_group`"...

I **want to access** with "`http://mysite.com/groups/test_group`"

How to achieve it without mention the `index.php` with parameter segment in Core PHP?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/gaggletrips/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gaggletrips/

RewriteRule ^(groups)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Once these rules are in place you can directly type `http://mysite.com/groups/test_group` and it will load `http://mysite.com/groups/index.php?name=test_group` behind the scenes without changing URL in the browser.

Comment: I got `Object not found! 404 Error` when accessing the URL: `http://localhost/gaggletrips/groups/test_group` My local server successfully enabled **mod_rewrite** through **httpd.conf**... help me... thanks for your time...

Comment: What is `gaggletrips`? You never mentioned that there is another directory in between

Comment: See the code above **`to be placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT/gaggletrips/.htaccess file`**

Comment: I have mentioned in example `http://mysite.com/groups/test_group` **mysite.com->gaggletrips** , **gaggletrips** is the root directory and i have placed .htaccess file in gaggletrips diretory anubhava